# If for any $r\in\Gamma$ $d(A_r) $is closed and $A=\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r $,can we have $d(A)$ closed?

Tags: general-topology

d(A) denotes the derived set of A,that is $x\in d(A)$ if and only if for any neighborhood $U$ of $x$:$U\cap(A-x)\ne \varnothing$.

If $\Gamma$ is a finite set, this statement is true,since $d(A\cup B)=d(A)\cup d(B).$ But in general,$d(\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r)\supset\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}d(A_r)$.

Answer (score 2):

No, the inclusion is the other way around!

Take $A_q = \{q\}$, $q \in \Bbb Q$ in the reals, usual topology.

Then $d(A_q)=\emptyset$ for all $q$ but $d(\bigcup_{q \in \Bbb Q}) = d(\Bbb Q)= \Bbb R$. So not $d(\bigcup_q A_q) \subset \bigcup_q d(A_q)$.

But $A \subset B$ implies $d(A) \subset d(B)$.

So $d(A_r) \subseteq d(\bigcup_{r \in \Gamma} A_r)$ from $A_r \subseteq \bigcup_{r \in \Gamma} A_r$.

So it follows that $\bigcup_{r \in \Gamma} d(A_r) \subseteq d(\bigcup_{r \in \Gamma} A_r)$ instead. And this can be strictly smaller, as we've seen.

Comment: Sorry,I made a mistake while typing.In fact, if we had $d(\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}A_r)\subset\bigcup\limits_{r\in\Gamma}d(A_r)$,which is wrong,then the statement can be proved easily.Any way,thanks for the counter example.